# Can RaphaelJS be object aware?

Tags: svg, raphael

In the course of trying to figure out whether it's possible to contain text within the boundaries of a rectangle using [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/index.html) (and without doing what would seem to be a *lot* of work), I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355208/how-can-i-stop-elements-overlapping-using-javascript-and-the-raphael-javascript-l) (and its answer) which intrigued me.

I haven't seen--either before or since reading the answer--any indication that Raphael can do anything like this. My sense, therefore, is that it's a glib answer, but the concept is compelling and I'm just breaking into some Raphael work, so I thought it was worth shining the spotlight on that answer and asking for any clarification someone may be able to give.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hope this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659206/detecting-wether-a-point-is-inside-or-outside-of-a-raphael-js-shape)